# Does updating software on Ubuntu slow down the OS?

Tags: updates

Most of the time I update software on Ubuntu. The software consumes a lot of space on my storage device. Is continuous updating of software one reason for Ubuntu performing slow?

Comment: Not unless the update introduces a bug

Comment: @bodhi.zazen After the software gets updated, does the OS automatically removes the previous version and free the space?

Comment: In general yes, but there are exceptions, such as old kernels

Comment: In some cases, the .deb files that were downloaded remain on your system, but these shouldn't take up too much space. You can run `sudo apt-get autoclean` to get rid of .deb files for older versions of programs and `sudo apt-get clean` to get rid of all .deb files (you can download them later again).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what packages you are installing, and how much your computer can take. Unless the software packages are using a lot of memory, or your hard drive isalmost completely full, updating software packages shouldn't slow your computer down.

Answer (score 1):

It may or may not. Updates oftentimes introduce greater functionality to the older version of the program, thus causing the program to consume greater memory and/or cpu. Other times, updates may fix bugs that would otherwise uselessly consume memory and/or cpu. On the other hand, updates may also introduce new bugs that also uselessly consume cpu and memory. You should check with the package and software maintainers to see what types of updates are included in the updated packages and in any future updates.